# Resolving a class instance via constructor parameter with Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a basic page component like so:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Events } from "ionic-angular";
import { Socket } from "../../../Socket/Socket";

@Component({
    selector: "page-leaderboard",
    templateUrl: "Leaderboard.html"
})
export class LeaderboardPage {

    constructor(public events: Events, public socket: Socket) {
    }

    ionViewWillEnter() {
        this.events.subscribe("leaderboard.open", () => {
            console.log("leaderboard.open");
        });
    }

    ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.socket.emit("get leaderboard data");
    }
}
```

However, this code has a problem. It injects the class and not the class instance, which means I have to use

```
constructor(public events: Events, public socket: Socket) {
    this.socket = new Socket;
    this.socket.connect();
}
```

on constructor to make it work.

I don't want to create a new instance of my socket object. Ideally, it should be a singleton that is passed via reference into components.

How can I do this instead?

```
// app.components.ts or app.modules.ts, or somewhere else
import { Socket } from "App/Socket/Socket";

let socket = new Socket; // put this into Angular's DI Container somehow
socket.connect().then(() => {
   console.log("Socket connected");
});

---

// Components
constructor(public events: Events, public socket: Socket) {
    this.socket = Socket; // "class instance" should be injected here
}
```

Thanks alot!

Comment: The behavior you're describing doesn't make much sense. Anyway, did you add the `Socket` to the `@NgModule.providers`?

Comment: @peeskillet It does. Why would you need different instances of socket.io? It listens for backend related events and publishes angular events for components to rely on. Ps. Socket is already defined on providers.

Comment: Since Socket is your custom implementation, please add what you have for that as well as how it's being provided into the question. Injecting the class and not the class instance makes me wonder if your implementation is Injectable()